# Recover SBS 2003 CALs

Tags: windows-sbs-2003, cal

My SBS 2003 CALs have reset back to five after some weird server issues. I don't have a backup of the CAL licenses anywhere is there somewhere I can restore these from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per this link
http://blog.chrisara.com.au/2006/09/small-business-server-2003-dreaded-5.html

After much stuffing about I found that the SBS2003 licenses are kept in the licstr.cpa file in the WINDOWS\system32 folder. Thankfully, Microsoft actually keep an automatic backup of this in autolicstr.cpa. The simple process was to stop the License Logging Service, rename licstr.cpa to licstr.cpa.old, then copy autolicstr.cpa to licstr.cpa. After this I started License Logging Service and used Server Management to confirm that the licenses had been restored.